# The complexity of computing the permanent of a matrix of zeroes and ones versus a matrix of integers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, matrices, permanent

How much easier is computing the permanent of a matrix with only zeroes and ones than a matrix of only integers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a polynomial-time reduction from one problem to the other, as explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete#01-Matrix) among other places.

Comment: Very nice. I never saw that before.

Answer (score 2):

The [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of a [01-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%280,1%29-matrix) is equal to the number of [vertex cycle covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover) of an unweighted directed graph. Its computation is [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete).